# Consider the class LinkedListWithIterator, Provide a remove operation for the inner class IteratorForLinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list, iterator, inner-classes, remove-method

For my project in my class I have to provide a remove method for  the inner class IteratorForLinkedList. Note you will needanother data field. Include interface definition, class implementing the interface, and the test program. I have tried my best I just want to make sure I did what the assignment was done correclty. Here is what I have done already.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
public class LinkedListWithIterator<T> implements ListWithIteratorInterface<T> {
    
    private Node firstNode;
    private int numberOfEntries;
    
    public LinkedListWithIterator() {
        initaliazeDataFields();
    }
    /**
     * Implementation for the ft list go here chapter 12, starting at 
     * segment 12.7
     * @return
     */
    public void clear() {
        initaliazeDataFields();
    }
    
    private void initaliazeDataFields() {
        firstNode = null;
        numberOfEntries = 0;
    }
    
    private Node getNodeAt(int givenPosition) {
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
        for (int counter = 1; counter < givenPosition; counter++)
            currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode;
        
        return currentNode;
    }
    
    public void add(T newEntry) {
        Node newNode = new Node(newEntry);
        
        if (isEmpty())
            firstNode = newNode;
        else {
            Node lastNode = getNodeAt(numberOfEntries);
            lastNode.setNextNode(newNode);
        }
        numberOfEntries++;
    }
    
    public void add(int givenPosition, T newEntry) {
        if ((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= numberOfEntries + 1)) {
            Node newNode = new Node(newEntry);
            
            if(givenPosition == 1) {
                newNode.setNextNode(firstNode);
                firstNode = newNode;
            } else {
                Node nodeBefore = getNodeAt(givenPosition - 1);
                Node nodeAfter = nodeBefore.getNextNode();
                newNode.setNextNode(nodeAfter);
                nodeBefore.setNextNode(newNode);
            }
            numberOfEntries++;
        } else
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("illegal position given to add operation");
    } // end add
    
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        boolean result;
        if (numberOfEntries == 0) {
            result = true;
        } else {
            result = false;
        } 
        return result;
    }
    
    public T[] toArray() {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] result = (T[])new Object[numberOfEntries];
        
        int index = 0;
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
        while ((index < numberOfEntries) && (currentNode != null)) {
            result[index] = currentNode.getData();
            currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
            index++;
        }
        return result;
    } // end to array
    
    
    
    public T remove(int givenPosition) {
        T result = null;
        if((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= numberOfEntries)) {
            if (givenPosition == 1) {
                result = firstNode.getData();
                firstNode = firstNode.getNextNode();
            } else {
                Node nodeBefore = getNodeAt(givenPosition - 1);
                Node nodeToRemove = nodeBefore.getNextNode();
                result = nodeToRemove.getData();
                Node nodeAfter = nodeToRemove.getNextNode();
                nodeBefore.setNextNode(nodeAfter);
            }
            numberOfEntries--;
            return result;
            
        } else {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("illegal position given to remove ");
        }
    } // end remove
    
    public T replace(int givenPosition, T newEntry) {
        if((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= numberOfEntries)) {
            Node desiredNode = getNodeAt(givenPosition);
            T originalEntry = desiredNode.getData();
            return originalEntry;
        }
        else
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Illegal Position given for replace method ");
    } // end replace
    
    public T getEntry(int givenPosition) {
        if ((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= numberOfEntries)) {
            return getNodeAt(givenPosition).getData;
        } 
        else 
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Illegal Position given for getentry method ");
    } // end get entry
    
    public boolean contains(T anEntry) {
        boolean found = false;
        Node currentNode = firstNode;
        
        while(!found && (currentNode != null)) {
            if(anEntry.equals(currentNode.getData())) {
                found = true;
            } else {
                currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode;
            }
            
        }
        return found;
    }
    
    
    
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return new IteratorForLinkedList();
    }
    
    public Iterator getIterator() {
        return iterator();
    }
    
    private class IteratorForLinkedList implements Iterator<T> {
        private Node nextNode;
        
        private IteratorForLinkedList() {
            nextNode = firstNode;
        }
        
        public T next() {
            T result;
            if (hasNext()) {
                result = nextNode.getData;
            } else {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("Illegal call to next(); iterator is after end of list");
            }
            return result;
        }
        
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextNode != null;
        }
        
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Remove() is not supported by this operator");
        }
    }
    
    // Implementation for private class node
    
    private class Node 
    {
        public T getData;
        public LinkedListWithIterator<T>.Node getNextNode;
        private T data;
        private Node next;
        
        private Node(T dataPortion) {
            this(dataPortion, null);
        }
        
        private Node(T dataPortion, Node nextNode) {
            data = dataPortion;
            next = nextNode;    
        }
        
        private T getData() {
            return data;
        }
        
        private void setData(T newEntry) {
            data = newEntry;
        }
        
        private Node getNextNode() {
            return next;
        }
        
        private void setNextNode(Node nextNode) {
            next = nextNode;
        }
    } // end node class
    
}
```

Comment: "_I just want to make sure I did what the assignment was done correclty_" - Does it work? What is your specific question?

Comment: Well the textbook says that there isn’t a provided remove method for the inner class iterator. So is this how I would remove a entry that the iterator has just passed over? Sorry I’m just not clear on what I should be doing.

Comment: I think you need clarification from your teacher. I don't think we can answer that.